# Bootstrap 4 file input with bs-custom-file-input and Symfony 5 collection with dynamic upload fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony, bootstrap-4

The main problem (no label for choosen filname in bootstrap 4 upload field) was solved with the plugin (https://github.com/Johann-S/bs-custom-file-input)

You can use the "bs-custom-file-input"
to display the choosen filename in the bootstrap 4 file upload field.

But this does not work when I use array Collections in my FormType.
(to add multiple dynamically new upload fields in my form)

I use this example to add mutiple dynamic upload fields:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

This example adds html code dynamically - so I can have many Upload Fields. The problem is that bs-custom-file-input does not work with dynamcally created new Upload Fields but only with a standalone normal Upload Field.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    bsCustomFileInput.init()
    // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
    var $tagsCollectionHolder = $('ul.assignment_documents');
    // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
    // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
    $tagsCollectionHolder.data('index', $tagsCollectionHolder.find('input').length);

    $('body').on('click', '.add_item_link', function(e) {
        var $collectionHolderClass = $(e.currentTarget).data('collectionHolderClass');
        // add a new tag form (see next code block)
        addFormToCollection($collectionHolderClass);
    })
});


function addFormToCollection($collectionHolderClass) {
    // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
    var $collectionHolder = $('.' + $collectionHolderClass);

    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

    var newForm = prototype;
    // You need this only if you didn't set 'label' => false in your tags field in TaskType
    // Replace '__name__label__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    // newForm = newForm.replace(/__name__label__/g, index);

    // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    newForm = newForm.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
    // Add the new form at the end of the list
    $collectionHolder.append($newFormLi)

}
```

Comment: Show us what you are actually doing in your code, insted of saying “doesn’t work”! _“The problem is that bs-custom-file-input does not work with dynamcally created new Upload Fields”_ - looking at the docs, my first guess would be that you probably need to call the `init` method again, to initialize the plugin for your newly added fields as well, it is not likely to do that on its own, such plugins usually don’t “watch” the DOM for changes.

Comment: yes, I have found the solution, just add "bsCustomFileInput.init()" at the end of the addFormToCollection() function, this does the magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add "bsCustomFileInput.init()" at the end of the addFormToCollection() function, this does the magic.

```
function addFormToCollection($collectionHolderClass) {
    // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
    var $collectionHolder = $('.' + $collectionHolderClass);

    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

    var newForm = prototype;
    // You need this only if you didn't set 'label' => false in your tags field in TaskType
    // Replace '__name__label__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    // newForm = newForm.replace(/__name__label__/g, index);

    // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    newForm = newForm.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
    // Add the new form at the end of the list
    $collectionHolder.append($newFormLi)

    bsCustomFileInput.init()
}
```